# Encountering an error in VoteSurvey component while using Firebase in React. C

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, survey

When I remove the `VoteSurvey.jsx` page from `Home.jsx`, my application works. I don't know how to create a survey using Firebase.

https://github.com/ahmetsedr/SurveyApp

I would like to add a survey using AddSurvey and display the data in Home.jsx using VoteSurvey, then submit the form and display the survey results.

AddSurvey is a form component that allows users to add surveys by providing the necessary information and questions.